# Multivariable Taylor's Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, taylor-expansion

I chanced upon this lemma when studying differential geometry which seems to depend on Taylor's theorem, but I have never seen it before, could someone explain how the proof works? I am not sure how this follows from Taylor's theorem, if at all. It seems to me like some kind of linearization, and hence perhaps related to Taylor's theorem.

**Lemma:** Let $h\in C^{\infty}(U)$, where $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then there exists smooth functions $h_{i}\in C^{\infty}(U)$ such that 
\begin{equation}
h(u)=h(0)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}u^{i}h_{i}
\end{equation}
where $u=(u^{1},...,u^{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Note that $h_{i}(0)=\frac{\partial h}{\partial u^{i}}|_{u=0}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$h(x) = h(0) + \int_0^1 Dh(tx) x dt = h(0) + \sum_k x_k \int_0^1 [Dh(tx)]_k  dt $.

Let $h_k (x) = \int_0^1 [Dh(tx)]_k  dt $.